# Merge overlapping multiword in python

Tags: python, string, list, merge

I have a list of multiword, for example:

```
['President Barack', 'Barack Obama', 'New York', 'York City', 'United States', 'States of America', 'This is not overlapping']
```

I want to merge overlapping multiword to obtain something like this:

```
['President Barack Obama', 'New York City', 'United States of America', 'This is not overlapping']
```

I have tried this code taken from another similar question:

```
strFrag = ['President Barack', 'Barack Obama', 'New York', 'York City', 'United States', 'States of America', 'This is not overlapping']

for repeat in range(0, len(strFrag)-1):
    bestMatch = [2, '', ''] #overlap score (minimum value 3), otherStr index, assembled str portion
    for otherStr in strFrag[1:]:
        for x in range(0,len(otherStr)):
            if otherStr[x:] == strFrag[0][:len(otherStr[x:])]:
                if len(otherStr)-x > bestMatch[0]:
                    bestMatch = [len(otherStr)-x, strFrag.index(otherStr), otherStr[:x]+strFrag[0]]
            if otherStr[:-x] == strFrag[0][-len(otherStr[x:]):]:
                if x > bestMatch[0]:
                    bestMatch = [x, strFrag.index(otherStr), strFrag[0]+otherStr[-x:]]
    if bestMatch[0] > 2:
        strFrag[0] = bestMatch[2]
        strFrag = strFrag[:bestMatch[1]]+strFrag[bestMatch[1]+1:]
```

But it works only for the first word of the list, giving me this result:

```
['President Barack Obama', 'New York', 'York City', 'United States', 'States of America', 'This is not overlapping']
```

My question is: how would you solve it?

Thank you for your time!

EDIT: I want that only near words are merged, so if I have ['President Barack', 'Some word', 'Other word', 'Barack Obama'], President Barack Obama will not merge.

UPDATE: maybe something like this is correct but if possible I want your opinions about it

```
strFrag = ['President Barack', 'Barack Obama', 'Obama of the USA', 'New York', 'York City', 'Test', 'Hello how', 'how you doin?']

for i in range(len(strFrag)):
  strFrag[i] = strFrag[i].split()

for i in range(len(strFrag)-1,-1,-1):
    if (strFrag[i][0] == strFrag[i-1][-1]):
      strFrag[i-1].remove(strFrag[i-1][-1])
      strFrag[i] = strFrag[i-1] + strFrag[i]
      strFrag.remove(strFrag[i-1])

for i in range(len(strFrag)):
  strFrag[i] = ' '.join(strFrag[i])
```

It gives me:

```
['President Barack Obama of the USA',
 'New York City',
 'Test',
 'Hello how you doin?']
```

Comment: Do you want to join each phrase with the other one whose start has the most overlap? What if an ending phrase could be joined to two different starting phrases -- can you join to both separately or do you have to join to just one of them? If it's the latter, which start should the ending phrase be joined to -- the first in the list or the one with the most overlap? Can you join chains of multiple phrases -- double and triple overlaps, etc.?

Comment: I want to join only phrase that are near to each other, because in my dataset I have long lists of phrases, and otherwise it will cause problems. I also want multiple chains if possible (example: (President Joe, Biden of, the United States) will be 'President Joe Biden of the United States', but only if they are near).

Answer (score 1):

I think i would solve it like this:

1. split each string with space
   ex : 'york City' => ['York','City']
2. look if the first and last word can be match with (resp.) the last and first word of another string
3. assemble these two strings if it works
4. repeat until you don't do any modifications
5. concatenate the string you found with the join method

If you want to match more than one word each time,
ex : 'the president barack' and 'president barack obama' becoming 'the president barack obama',
I would use a loop that consider the next or previous word of each string if the first or last already match

Hope I was clear enough and helped to solve your problem.

Comment: Can you provide some code of your method? I've tried this: for i in range(len(strFrag)):
  for j in range(len(strFrag)):
    if (strFrag[i][0] == strFrag[j][-1]):
      strFrag[i] = strFrag[j] + strFrag[i]  - but I don't think it is correct, because I get repetition like: ['President', 'Barack', 'Obama'] but also ['President', 'Barack']

Comment: im not gonna try to implement this now (it's kinda late in France) so maybe tomorrow i'll try to do it. Also i wrote this more like an idea than an actual answer (you know, not enough score to comment), I think it can work but if you encounter a problem that i didnt think of and it seems that this would never work, dont be too stubborn I was just trying to help a bit and give you a new path to follow.